# Dynamically setting a subclass's attr's based on database/table columns

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, subclass, attr, superclass

I need to retrieve the column names from various tables in a database in order to dynamically set `attr_accessor` methods for those tables corresponding classes. This needs to be done from a parent class.

```
class Child < Parent
  attr_accessor :id, :column_a, :etc.
end
```

`Parent`'s `#column_names` method does indeed work the way I intend it to. It returns an array of column names for whatever table is specified by the child class. HOWEVER, it does NOT return any column names when it is being called from the `#inherited` method. When I attempt to set `attr_accessor` methods for the child class, an empty array is returned.

I am attempting to set these `attr_accessor` methods dynamically, using `#class_eval` to insert them into the child class. This is where the call to `#column_names` happens and where it an empty array is returned.

```
module SomeModule
  class Parent

    def self.inherited(child)
      child.class_eval do
        self.column_names.each { |att| attr_accessor att.to_sym }
      end  
    end

    #...

    def self.table_name
      "#{self.to_s.downcase}s"
    end

    def self.column_names
      sql = "#... WHERE table_name = '#{table_name}';"

      columns = []
      exec(sql).each do |col-data|
        columns << col_data["column_name"]
      end

      columns
    end

    def self.exec(sql, args=[])
      #...
    end

    #...

  end
end
```

My understanding is that this should essentially create a call from `Child` to `Child.column_names` which, I think it does. I just don't know why the return array is not populated. I have experimented around with moving the `column_names` method around, but the only change in behaviour, depending on where it is placed, is a `NoMethodError` for the child class.

Comment: can you give a usage example for the module?

Comment: @max pleaner the module is basically an ORM - just a super light-weight version of ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the docs on [inherited](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) aren't very detailed, but I see what the problem is here - it's the value of `self` in the `class_eval` block.

The NoMethodError is because the `column_names` method is not defined on the child class, and self refers to the child class inside the `class_eval` block,

There's a simple fix, which is set `self` to a variable before the `class_eval` block.

Hopefully it's clear in the following example, which I tested and works. Note that the only real difference from your code is in the `inherited` method. All the other stuff is just there test it, because I can't really run-your code as-is.

```
require 'byebug'

class ParentClass
  def self.inherited(child)
    parent_class = self # Store value of self in a variable
                        # because it will change in class_eval
                        # Then call column_names on this variable
    child.class_eval do
        parent_class.column_names.each { |attr| attr_accessor attr.to_sym }
    end
  end
  def self.column_names
    [:foo, :bar]
  end
end

class ChildClass < ParentClass
  def initialize
  end
end

child = ChildClass.new
child.foo = "bar"
puts child.foo
# => "bar"
```

This problem is more common in javascript, which has more rigidly segregated scope levels. In other words, the value of `self` changes more frequently.

Comment: I gave this a shot, but no dice. It works, meaning that it does succeed in calling the proper column_names method, and it's fine if the return array is populated by hand. But calling it from within the `inherited` method still leaves the array empty.  I only get the `NoMethodError` if I move the `#column_name` method around. I've changed my approach and can make a call to an attr_setter method after the array has been populated and that works, but it's still a mystery to me why making a call to #column_names straight away makes it empty.

Comment: maybe try checking that table_name returns the correct value? You should use a debugger and step through your column names method.